# Is it wise to reduce the number of labels in a multi-class classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, multi-class

I'm working on a dataset which has 5 labels or the outcome, Y. I'm going to use ML model to predict the 5 labels. While doing the data analysis, I found that class1(60%), class2(39%),class3(0.33%), class4(0.63%) and class5(0.04%). Due to such high imbalance, I'm thinking of merging class3, class4 and class5 together. I think that these classes have so less observations that it is not useful to train my ML model for them separately.
Should I be aware of the pros and cons of this approach? Can I justify it?

Answer (score 1):

If prediction of those specific classes is not of particular interest, you can group them. Note that you should have a minimum number of observations per group in order to be able to even estimate your parameters correctly (I can't remember what the formula is off the top of my head). Grouping small classes to meet that minimum requirement is common. With such small %'s in classes 3-5, I am wondering if you might want to remove them from your problem entirely.